# set fixed number of zeroes before and after decimal in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to set the value of a field in table depending on conditions whose value I am getting from another table. The data type of this field is float. The requirement is I need to have 2 digits before decimal and 4 after. So if a value is 9.45, I need to set it 09.4500. I am wondering what might be the best way to do this. Should I convert the value into varchar and then do substring? Or can this be done setting precision?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, don't store such a value as a float.  You have described the `decimal(6, 4)`/`numeric(6, 4)` data type very closely.

If you have this as a `float` or `decimal`, you can use `str()` and then pad to the right:

```
select right('000000' + str(9.45, 6, 4), 7)
```